# Cannot establish connection with signalR

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

Connection created like below:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('http://localhost:44306/notify',
        { skipNegotiation: true, transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets, accessTokenFactory: () =>  "" }).
        build();

    this._hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));}
```

never starts => promise is not resolved

Backend configuration should not be a problem: Startup.cs

```
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<BroadcastMessage>("/notify");
        });
```

and

```
public class BroadcastMessage : Hub<ITypedHubClient>
{
}
public interface ITypedHubClient
{
    Task BroadcastMessage(string type, string payload);
}
```

signalrR library version 1.0.1

Comment: Are SignalR client and server in the same project? Could you share us the complete `Startup.cs`? Is there any error in web browser debug tool?

Comment: Since you're using ngOnInit your client and server are probably be hosted on different "servers". Which means you'll likely need to enable CORS and allow the client Origin. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#enable-cors-with-cors-middleware